# problem in synchronization of timer0 and CPU clock cycles

Tags: avr

I am a beginner in AVR. I need to sample input at odd intervals of 8 ms. i have used CTC mode for generating 8 ms timer. i used CTC with compare interrupt so that i can get a flag (timer_count) set at every comparison. i.e. after every 8 ms. The 8 ms timer starts on External Interrupt at PIN D0.
when i am checking the input conditions in main loop, due to large difference in frequency of main controller (18.432 MHz) and 8 ms timer, i am unable to sample inputs correctly. Can anyone tell me any other method to do this. The code is pasted here for reference.

#include <mega128.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#define CHECK_BIT(ADDRESS,BIT) (ADDRESS & (1<<BIT))

#define SET_BIT(ADDRESS,BIT) (ADDRESS |= (1<<BIT))

#define CLEAR_BIT(ADDRESS,BIT) (ADDRESS &= (~(1<<BIT)))

#define TGL_BIT(ADDRESS, BIT) (ADDRESS ^= (1<<BIT))

volatile unsigned int flag;

volatile unsigned int timer_count=0;

volatile unsigned int frequency_979_sense;

volatile unsigned int frequency_885_sense;

volatile unsigned int frequency_933_sense;

volatile unsigned int flag_979_received;

volatile unsigned int flag_885_received;

volatile unsigned int data;

volatile unsigned int i;

volatile unsigned char SOP_valid;

volatile unsigned int previous_state=0;

volatile unsigned int current_state=0;

// Timer 0 output compare interrupt service routine

interrupt [TIM0_COMP] void timer0_comp_isr(void)
{

timer_count++;

}

void init_timer0()
{

// Timer/Counter 0 initialization

// Clock source: System Clock

// Clock value: 18.000 kHz

// Mode: CTC top=OCR0

// OC0 output: toggle output on compare match

ASSR=0x00;

TCCR0=0x1F;

TCNT0=0x00;

OCR0=0x90;

// Timer(s)/Counter(s) Interrupt(s) initialization

TIMSK=0x02;

}

// External Interrupt 0 service routine

interrupt [EXT_INT0] void ext_int0_isr(void)
{

if ((CHECK_BIT(PIND,4)==0) & (CHECK_BIT(PIND,5)==0))

```
  {

  init_timer0();

  flag=1;

  CLEAR_BIT(EIMSK,0);

  CLEAR_BIT(EIFR,0);

}
```

}

void main(void)
{
// Port D initialization

PORTD=0xFF;

DDRD=0x00;

// External Interrupt(s) initialization

// INT0: On

// INT0 Mode: Rising Edge

EICRA=0x03;

EICRB=0x00;

EIMSK=0x01;

EIFR=0x01;

// Global enable interrupts

#asm("sei")

while (1)
{
while (timer_count > 0 & timer_count<32)

```
            {                                   
                if (timer_count%2==1) 
                {     
                    frequency_979_sense= CHECK_BIT(PIND,0);
                    frequency_885_sense= CHECK_BIT(PIND,4);
                    frequency_933_sense= CHECK_BIT(PIND,5); 
                    
                    if ((frequency_979_sense != 0) && (frequency_885_sense == 0) && (frequency_933_sense == 0) && (flag_885_received==0 || flag_885_received== 8)) 
                    {                                    
                              flag_979_received++;
                              SET_BIT(data,i);         
                    }

                    if ((frequency_979_sense == 0) && (frequency_885_sense != 0) && (frequency_933_sense == 0) && (flag_979_received==6)) 
                    { 
                              flag_885_received++;
                              SET_BIT(data,i); 
                    }   
                   else
                    {
                             flag_979_received=0;
                             flag_885_received=0;
                             frequency_979_sense=0;
                             frequency_885_sense=0;
                             frequency_933_sense=0; 
                             data=0;
                             TCCR0=0x00;
                             TIMSK=0x00;
                             timer_count=0;
                             i=0;
                             SET_BIT(EIMSK,0);
                             SET_BIT(EIFR,0);
                    }      
                }   
                               
               i++;
            }  
            
            if (data==65535) 
                 {
                   SOP_valid=1;
                 }
```

}
}

Comment: You need `OCR0=0x8F`, not 0x90

Comment: Actually the Micro controller is taking almost 147602 cycles before making timer_count from 1 to 2. In between the loop is unnecessarily executing, causing registers to store false values. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Set a flag in the timer interrupt, then wait for this flag to be set before reading the pins in your main loop.  Clear the flag before reading the pin states.  This way you only perform one measurement per timer period.  Specifically change `if (timer_count%2==1)` to `if (flag) { flag = 0; // rest of your logic }`.

Comment: the code is working fine if i comment else condition, but the clock is not generating if i uncomment else condition, what would be the reason behind this? Is this also due to differences in clocks?